# IIS - Website at port 8080 can be accessed using localhost but not with external IP address

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, ip, localhost

I have 3 websites running on my server, all of them on different ports. One is on port 80 and it works fine, the other one is on port 88 and it also works fine. Today I deployed a third one on port 8080, opened the port in Firewall.

I can access it with `http://localhost:8080/`, with `127.0.0.1:8080` and with it's internal IP address. I can't access it using the external IP address for some reason. I tried accessing it locally using the external IP address and I tried from another computer.

It is worth noting that the website on port 8080 is almost identical to the one on port 80.

Initially I thought it was a firewall issue but I disabled the firewall and tried again and I get the same result (The website took too long to respond).

I am using Windows 10 on the server.

Any ideas as to why this is happening?

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the answer. I am using an EC2 instance from Amazon Web Services for a server. I forgot to go into the console  in AWS and open the port there too. I did that and now it's working as it should.

Comment: That's the most common cause of such.

Comment: It seemed like that, didn't make sense after I opened the port on the firewall.

Answer (score 0):

There could be couple of reasons.

1. Cloud Provider(AWS) Specific

   1. Check your subnet's ACL rules. Both ingress and egress
   2. Check the security group attached to the instance. It should allow ingress
      on that port/protocol
2. Windows Server Firewall: All windows servers and desktops have firewall running which blocks any non-standard traffic. Make sure to add a custom rule to allow the traffic that you want to allow. I found this https://computingforgeeks.com/how-to-open-a-port-in-windows-server-firewall/ link helpful